# jQuery DataTable clickable Titles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, datatable

I'm showing following info using jquery datatables. 
ID, Titles, Address, City, ZipCode
The rows in ID just contains a link that links to details page of the product, which is nice, however the text says "View" for each and every row. This is silly. I would like to hide/remove the Id column and make Titles clickable, that is when a title is clicked then the user should be transferred to the details page. In other words I want the title column to take over the functionality of the Id column.

This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "DataTable/AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "ID",
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                return '<a href=\"' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                            }
                        },
                        { "sName": "TITLE" },
                        { "sName": "ADDRESS" },
                        { "sName": "CITY" },
                        { "sName": "ZIPCODE" }
                    ]
    });
});
```

I'm using MVC 2.0

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "DataTable/AjaxHandler",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "ID",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            return '<a href=\"' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "sName": "TITLE",
                      "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                        var al = oObj.aData[0].split('>');                          
                        var al2 = al[0].split('=');                         
                        var al3 = al2[1].split('/');                           
                        return "<a href='\" + al3[al3.length-1] + "'>"oObj.aData[1] + "</a>";
                    },"aTargets": [1]
```

},
                        { "sName": "ADDRESS" },
                        { "sName": "CITY" },
                        { "sName": "ZIPCODE" }
                    ]
    });
});

May be that help, it may not be perfect it might work

For hiding a column you can try following link
        [show/Hide column in datatable](http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)

Comment: Hi Amritpal Singh! The code you have provided does not work! What happens is that when I view the datatable in a browser the id's are still there (I want them to be gone) and the title are turned into links, which is good, this is also want I want, but the links dont work. PS. I think there is a syntax error at line : return "<a href='\" + al3[al3.length-1] + "'>"oObj.aData[1] + "</a>";  ,instead it should say: return "<a href='\" + al3[al3.length-1] + \"'>" + oObj.aData[1] + "</a>";

Comment: @user806345 Do you want id column not to appear. Please elaborate a little

Comment: @user806345 i have edited my answer you can check whether that solution suits you.

Comment: hi although I have used the exact answer above, it was in that direction the problem were to be solved. Thanks for you valuable answers

Answer (score 1):

Hi the code that you have provided does not work. I have managed to solve the problem myself, here is my final code for those that may be in same situation.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "DataTable/AjaxHandler",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                    { 
                        "sName": "TITLE", //index 1
                        "bSearchable": true,
                        "bSortable": true,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) 
                        {
                            return '<a href=\"' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">' + oObj.aData["1"] + '</a>';
                        }                             
                    }
                    ,
                    { 
                        "sName": "ADDRESS", //index 2
                        "bSearchable": true,
                        "bSortable": true,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) 
                        {
                            return oObj.aData["2"] 
                        }                             
                    }
                    ,
                                            { 
                        "sName": "CITY", //index 3
                        "bSearchable": true,
                        "bSortable": true,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) 
                        {
                            return oObj.aData["3"] 
                        }                             
                    }
                    ,
                                            { 
                        "sName": "ZIPCODE", //index 4
                        "bSearchable": true,
                        "bSortable": true,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) 
                        {
                            return oObj.aData["4"] 
                        }                             
                    }
                ]
    });
});
```